# For a PPL, do I pursue gliders or airplanes first?

Tags: flight-training, glider, ppl, airplane

I'm interested in pursuing a Private Pilot's License. I'm interested in both gliders and powered flight. Gliders look like fantastic fun and powered flight would be an amazing thing to have – I could take my family and friends for tons of day trips not otherwise possible. There are negatives to both – the glider club is an hour away, and powered aircraft are expensive. Does anyone have any insight on which would be better to do first?

Answer (score 4):

It's a no brainer. From a pure skill perspective, if practical, do gliders first.  You will acquire perceptions and fine handling skills, and develop instincts and habits (speed control, energy management) to a higher level without the complication of the engine. You have to master the more sensitive and difficult to coordinate controls of a glider (not to mention "one chance to land", which helps take away some of the fear of engine failures when flying power).  Those habits will serve you extremely well when transitioning to power.

Also, gliding is flying for pure sport, as opposed to sightseeing or going places, and is more of an involved pastime. Clubs are group activities that depend on volunteer support, and it's a bit paradoxical really; you need to participate in the group, to do what is essentially a solitary activity (except when giving rides). So you have to be willing to commit full days to the activity, as opposed to going to the airport for a couple hours and going home.

Then there's the sport of soaring itself. It's like sailboats. You either are into it, the game you play with the atmosphere, or you aren't.  You need to find that out. If you are, it'll become a lifetime pastime.  Many power pilots learn to fly, go places for a while, then taper off as the novelty fades and the expenses increase, but for most glider pilots who are hard core about it, that is their thing all their lives, like sailing fanatics.

Comment: Thank you! That is a really good way of putting it.

Comment: Not quite sure if I entirely follow the logic in your last paragraph - of course the hardcore fanatics live and breathe gliding, that's true of any hobby including powered flight. And just like PPLers who drift away, many glider pilots do too. To me, they're related but fundamentally different hobbies - some will live and breathe one or the other, both, or none but I don't think there's anything inherent to either which makes it more or less likely. It's like comparing motorbiking and sports cars - if you love it, you love it, and that's about the sum of it IMHO

Answer (score 3):

From my experience and personal opinion transition from powered flight (i.e. airplane) to a glider is fairly straightforward. Many of the skills you learn in the course of getting a private pilot certificate in an airplane directly transfer to learning to fly a glider.

Learning in a glider first, then a powered airplane would provide for some knowledge and skill transfer but would not be as effective and efficient as the other way around.

Although it would likely be much more expensive to become a pilot first in an airplane, if your primary/ultimate goal is to be able to take friends and family on day trips it might be a better choice to get a glider rating last.

Comment: Thanks! That’s helpful.

Comment: I agree.  The hard part of flying is landing with both you and the aircraft in one piece.  You can get a lot more landing practice in a powered plane, and the landings themselves can be more forgiving - if you screw things up too badly, you can almost always hit the throttle and go around.  With a glider, the hard part is learning to fly on tow.  The rest is more about developing judgement - where thermals are, whether you can make it back to the field, &c.